# querySelector to select closest ancestor without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<style type="text/css">
.card{
    background:green;
}
</style>
<div class="card">
    inside first
    <div class="card" id="tryingtoselectthis">
        inside second
        <div class="card" id="myselector">
            inside third
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log(document.querySelector("#myselector").closest(".card"));
</script>
```

I am trying to select `#tryingtoselectthis` with the selector of `.myselector` just using the class. Please note that there can be an unlimited number of child with the same class and all I want to do is select the just above parent with the same class.

`parentNode` doesn't work. And, it is necessary to select the node using its class name.

No jQuery

Comment: You have mentioned `parentNode` doesn't work. But in my answer it is working as expected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're almost there, but if you don't want the element you initially selected to be a possible result, you'll have to call `closest` on its parent, not on the selected element.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("#myselector").parentElement.closest(".card").id);
```

```css
.card {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  inside first
  <div class="card" id="tryingtoselectthis">
    inside second
    <div class="card" id="myselector">
      inside third
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that ancient browsers like IE will require a polyfill.

[Element.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

Comment: Alternative to `.parentElement` would be `.closest('selector:not(:scope)')`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. If your parent Id is fixed.

```js
var el=document.querySelector('#myselector'); 
var closestelement = el.closest('#tryingtoselectthis.card');

console.log(closestelement)
```

```html
<div class="card">
    inside first
    <div class="card" id="tryingtoselectthis">
        inside second
        <div class="card" id="myselector">
            inside third
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can find Pollyfill for closest in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) site

Answer (score 0):

Using the following will pass through every parent element till it finds a matching element or till it reaches document which is not an instance of HTMLElement

```js
function findParent(element, selector) {
  let result = null;
  while(!result && (element = element.parentElement) instanceof HTMLElement) {
    if(element.matches(selector))
      result = element;
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(findParent(document.getElementById('myselector'), '#tryingtoselectthis'))
```

```html
<div class="card">
    inside first
    <div class="card" id="tryingtoselectthis">
        inside second
        <div class="card">
            inside third
          <div class="card" id="myselector">
              inside third
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That does not necessarily select the "above parent with the same class".